# How to make 3D parallel coordinates plot in r

Tags: r, plot, parallel-coordinates

I´m looking for a R package to plot 3d parallel coordinates plot.

It looks like so:

[image]

Do you known any package?

Comment: What does a 3d parallel coordinates plot look like? Can you include or link to an image?

Comment: Start with the rgl package - it can do 3d dynamic graphics. I don't know of anything for doing 3d parallel coordinates plots, but it should be fairly easy to build with rgl:lines3d calls.

Answer (score -2):

There are quite a few.  Via google searches ["3d parallel coordinates plot in r"](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=3d+parallel+coordinates+plot+in+r&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) and ["parcoord r"](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=parcoord+r&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)

[1](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/MASS/html/parcoord.html)
[2](http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/interactive.html)

Comment: thank you so much but I did it befor, but I didn´t find anything relevant.

Comment: did you still need help?  If yes, edit your question.  If not, could you mark it as answered?

Comment: you could start off by listing the packages you have found and why they were or were not useful.  People will be more likely if you have an example of how you'd like to utilize the package.